# Update arrays with React form

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, forms, web

I'm React beginner and I've a question. I want to update some arrays with a form. I have these arrays.

```
state = {
            loading: true,
            projects: [],
            tokens: [] ,
            authors: [] ,
            branches: [] }
```

Then i have 2 SELECT and a INPUT. When a select a value from a select (e.g: a value from select "branch"), i want to add the value to his array (in this example, to "branches"). When I complete the 3 form elements, there have to be 2 buttons.

1 - "Submit" button the form with current arrays.

2 - "Add" button to add current values to their arrays.

```
                                <div class='forminput'>
                                    <label for="key" id="keyLabel" class="login-label"><strong>Project key</strong></label>
                                    <select id="key"
                                        name="key"
                                        class="login-input"
                                        onChange={this.onChangeProject} required>
                                        {projectsList}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class='forminput'>
                                    <label for="branch" id="branchLabel" class="login-label"><strong>Branch key</strong></label>
                                    <select id="branch"
                                        name="branch"
                                        class="login-input" required>
                                        {branchesList}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class='forminput'>
                                    <label for="author" id="authorLabel" class="login-label"><strong>Author</strong></label>
                                    <input type="text"
                                        id="author"
                                        name="author"
                                        class="login-input"
                                        maxlength="255"
                                        required
                                        placeholder="Report's author" value={this.state.author}
                                        onChange={this.onChangeAuthor} />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token_cnesreport" defaultValue={this.state.token} />
                                </div>
<button type="button" onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add</button>
<input id="generation" name="generation" type="submit" value="Generate" /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to keep setting the state when the user is making changes on the form, so you will have all the data in the state already when the form is done

```
handleInputChange(event){
        this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
    }
```